# jqPlot MeterGaugeRenderer - set diameter causes error

Tags: internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3, jqplot

I am showing multiple Meter Gauges on a single page, in conjunction with Bootstrap, to provide responsiveness. What is obvious is they are all calculating slightly different sizes, so I hoped to use diameter.

Here is my working code:
    s1 = [322];

```
$.jqplot('spend',[s1],{
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.MeterGaugeRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
           min: 100,
           max: 500,
           intervals:[200, 300, 400, 500],
           intervalColors:['#66cc66', '#93b75f', '#E7E658', '#cc6666'],
           intervalOuterRadius: 56,
           ringColor: '#222',
           padding: 3,
           tickColor: '#111',
           ringWidth: 4,
           needleThickness: 11,
           shadowOffset: 10,
           label: "£"
        }
    },
    title: 'Spend'
});
```

If I add

```
diameter:200,
```

I get no output, and:

```
'this._center.0' is null or not an object  jqplot.meterGaugeRenderer.js, line 616 character 13
'this._center.0' is null or not an object  jqplot.meterGaugeRenderer.js, line 616 character 13
```

I have also tried

```
diameter:50,
```

and

```
diameter:500,
```

in case I was not providing adequate space, or too much space, but I rather doubt it, as intervalOuterRadius is set at 56, I have also assumed that

```
diameter:200
```

is correct syntax given that

```
intervalOuterRadius:56
```

(as well as various other values) is correct. I cannot find anyone else who has had this problem, and have had no response on the jqplot google group.

Oh yeah, and I'm primarily writing for IE8 atm but it will need to be used on ie11 in time.

Comment: For anyone else who is stuck on this, you need to put the `diameter: 200` outside the `seriesDefaults` section.